# Find the number of points of intersection

Tags: combinatorics

There are two lines $L_1$ and $L_2$, which contain $m$ and $n$ points respectively. If each of $m$ points of $L_1$ be joined to each of the $n$ points of $L_2$ by straight line terminated by the points, then excluding the given points, then the no of points of intersection ?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I thought that if we choose any two points form $L_1$ and any two points from and try to join them in all possible ways, then there will be one intersection point and so on

Comment: Actually I don't have any answer, so I want to confirm that am I correct or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are correct

$${m \choose 2}*{n \choose 2}$$
$\Rightarrow$
$$\frac{(mn)(m-1)(n-1)}{4}$$

Comment: I don't understand. How does this confirm something in the question as correct? No result is given in the question.

Comment: I want to say that @UMD is correct.

Comment: Yes, you did say that, but correct about what?

Comment: That HE/SHe is thinking right